# one-to-many mapping with property-ref not on primary key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a problem which I can't solve. Maybe someone of you have encountered a similar problem.

I have two classes - Person and Contact and mapping to load all contacts for person. Those examples are all simplified for better reading.

**Person.cs**

```
public class Person
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public long ObjectId { get; set; }
   public IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

**Contact.cs**

```
public class Contact
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Person.hbm.xml**

```
<property name="ObjectId" type="System.Int64" column="OBJECTID" />
<bag name="Contacts" lazy="true" cascade="all">
   <key column="PERSON_OBJECTID" property-ref="ObjectId" not-null="true" />
   <one-to-many class="Contact" />
</bag>
```

Contacts does not have any mapping for Persons, they just don't need it.

One person can have multiple contacts and one contact can have only one owner. But I create versions of persons when some of their data changes, because I need to keep history of changes. So tables look like this:

**PERSONS TABLE**

```
----------------------------------------
| ID | OBJECTID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |
----------------------------------------
| 1  |    100   |   David   |   Gray   |
| 2  |    100   |   David   |   Gray   |
| 3  |    100   |   David   |   Gray   |
----------------------------------------
```

**CONTACTS TABLE**

```
--------------------------------------------
| ID | PERSON_OBJECTID |        TEXT       |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |       100       | email@email.com   |
| 2  |       100       | some phonenumber  |
--------------------------------------------
```

I don't want to duplicate `CONTACTS` table rows each time a version is created for the `PERSON` - so I want to use ObjectId field instead which is always same for one person. This mapping successfully saves the data to database, but do not always retrieve it successfully. Sometimes I get error

> Initializing[Person#100]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of
>   role: Person.Contacts, no session or session was closed

In the error I can see that it shows me an #ObjectId, usually there's an #Id. Maybe there's some NHibernate bug related to that problem? That it's messes up property-ref property with primary key. Or is there some other way not to create another table (I can create a table where I hold persons Id and objectId)?.

If I map my tables with primary keys, then all works like a charm, but I get unwanted result - i must copy all contacts from previous version to current and in contacts table there's a huge amount of duplicate rows.

**EDIT:**

The SQL select clause sample for what I want to achieve is something like that:

```
select c.* from persons p
inner join contacts c on c.person_objectid = p.objectid
where p.id = 1;
```

So, can you help me please? :)

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a strange issue in NH assoicated with property-ref, you need, for some reason, even if it is not true, to add - unique="true" to the property-ref mappings.

try this in Person.hbm.xml -

```
<property name="ObjectId" type="System.Int64" column="OBJECTID" unique="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your solution doesn't seem to work, I got still same errors that session is closed. Interesting part for this issue is that in some cases it works, in some cases not.

Comment: I see, are you making any queries on class Contact by itself? There might be 2 other reasons for this issue. First - you forgot to set hbm   XML file to embedded resource. second - You need to initialize Contact list in Person constructor.

Comment: This is all done. I had already another solution for this, but this is a hack - I made a view and there's two columns - persons Id and ObjectId and then I map this Contacts bag to this view instead. Then it works too. Also with this hack I had to add persons ObjectId property to Contact mapping and domain object. Finally needed to add two triggers to database, because NH wants to insert and update when there's no need :)

Comment: I recently encountered this issue myself, I load an object from a table and return it via a web service. The web service serialize the object, touching all properties including an inner collection invoking the lazy loader. But at this point the DB connection is already closed, resulting in an exception. The solution is the change lazy to false in Contacts <bag> mapping.